# Angular ng-change not working on directive's template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I'm trying to make a hinting ajax search box with an Angular directive. I'm still begining to match data and here is what I have:

```
function hintSearch () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div class="search_hint"><label><input type="search" ng-change="query()"></label><ul class="results"><li class="hint" ng-repeat="hint in hints | limitTo: 8" ng-bind="hint" ng-click="hint_selected(hint)"></li></ul></div>',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.hints = ["client1", "client2"];
            scope.hint_selected = function(){
                console.log("hint selected");
            }
            scope.query = function(){
                console.log("query php");
            scope.hints = ["client1", "client2", "client3"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `ng-change` gives me an error. With `ng-click` or `ng-keypress` it works perfectly so it makes no sense! Any ideas?

This is the error it throws:

```
angular.js:13550 Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngChange
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:6:412
    at gb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:71:251)
    at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:66:67)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:58:305)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:58:322)
    at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:65:473)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:58:305)
    at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:65:473)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js:58:305)
```

Comment: i will put the functions in the controller part not link

Comment: `input[search]` is not supported by angular and therefore I guess the `ngChange` will not work. Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891229/search-box-in-angular-js

Comment: Is that input element inside the label element done on purpose?

Comment: @Fidel90 I've tried to change input to text and it throws the same error. It must be something else, but I'll leave it as input[text] from now just in case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From error page](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngChange):

> This error occurs when HTML compiler tries to process a directive that
>   specifies the require option in a directive definition, but the
>   required directive controller is not present on the current DOM
>   element (or its ancestor element, if ^ was specified).

[This is the source code of `ng-change`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngChange.js#L3).

```
var ngChangeDirective = valueFn({
  restrict: 'A',
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
    ctrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
      scope.$eval(attr.ngChange);
    });
  }
});
```

`ng-model` is required for `ng-change`, there is no `ng-model` in your `input`.

```
<input type="search" ng-change="query()">
```

Add `ng-model` to your `input`, hope that will solve your problem.

```
<input type="search" ng-model='myModel' ng-change="query()">
```